# how do i load plugin from sdf model in ros

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similarly like i can put a plugin in urdf file and than when i launch that urdf in gazebo i can control that robot, isn't their any way how i can contol the robot model. I tried to use this line in my launch file but its not working:

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find <my_robot>)/model.sdf"/>
```

So is their any way how i can use the plugin from sdf robot to my gazebo ros control package or robot_description src file similarly like i did with urdf file. Like when i launchdd the urdf file with plugins in them, i can communicate with the robot from my plugin file than use ros control. Similarly i loaded the sdf robot in my world file than when i launchd it from my roslaunch file the plugin is not loaded.
Why i want to do this was, because so many robot models like r2, kuka and others where present in sdf format so i want to communicate them from my ros package.
I am using ros indigo and gazebo 7.4 for robot simulation.

Why is this happening that when i spawn a urdf robot in gazebo rviz and ros can communicate with it by plugins but not with sdf robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251293/how-do-i-load-plugin-from-sdf-model-in-ros/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you gone through [ros_gzplugins tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins)? Either way, it'd be helpful for others if you share the resources you referred to, and also share the codes you used. (i.e. by verbally saying `when i launchdd the urdf file with plugins in them, i can communicate with the robot from my plugin file than use ros control` doesn't make much concrete sense to others unfortunately).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0